# Agreement of a basis with a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have difficulty understanding the following definition in E.B. Vinberg's algebra book on Chapter 5, Vector Spaces:

> [Definition 5.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=kd24d3mwaecC&pg=PA172). A basis of a space $V$ *agrees* with a subspace $U$ if $U$ is a linear span of some basis vectors (i.e., if it is one of the "coordinate subspaces" with respect to this basis).

Isn't it obvious that every basis of a vector space spans a subspace of that vector space? What distinguishes "agrees with a subspace" from "is spanned by the basis of a vector space"?

Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Comment: In future, when you have a mathematical expression, please write the dollar sign both in front **and** behind it. Like so: `$U$`, not just `$U`. I edited the question for you this time.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

When we are dealing with that definition, there are two objects given from the start: the subspace $U$ and the basis $B$. If, for instance $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $U=\{(x,x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $B$ is the canonical basis, then $U$ *does not* agree with $B$.

Comment: I always find it comforting and a little amusing to see the same counterexample in another answer written in parallel to mine :).

Comment: Me too. But your answer was appeared first.

Comment: Sure, but they were clearly written in parallel. I mean, it's (arguably) the simplest possible counterexample, and the fact that we both went for it is further proof of that

Comment: I agree. It couldn't be simpler.

Comment: But, what about the subspace $z = 0$ with the basis $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$, do they agree?

Comment: No, that subspace and that basis don't agree.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Are you sure? Isn't the subspace $z=0$ spanned by $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\}$?

Comment: When I posted my comment, what was written there was not $z=0$. It was, $x+y=0$. As you can see the OP's comment was edited.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to see on an example. Let $V=\mathbb R^2$.

The basis $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ **agrees** with the subspace $U=\{(x,0)|x\in\mathbb R\}$.

The basis $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ **does not agree** with the subspace $U=\{(x,x)|x\in\mathbb R\}$.

---

The answer to your question should now be more clear, but just in case:

> Isn't it obvious that every basis of a vector space spans a subspace of that vector space?

Yes, this is obvious. If $B$ is a basis for $V$, then for every subset $S\subseteq U$, $S$ spans **some** subspace of $V$. And on those subspaces, $U$ *agrees* with them. However, there can (and do) also exist subspaces of $V$ which are *not* spanned by any subset of $U$. We say that does not agree with those subspaces.